# Xcode won't archive Swift iOS app with a Swift framework as a separate target. How can this be fixed?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, module, compilation

I have an iOS app that I've created using Swift.  Since I have a widget in my project and I want to share code between my widget and my app, I have a Swift framework also as part of my project.  I can successfully build my app.  First I have to build the framework, then I can build the app.  However, when I try to archive the app for distribution, it fails with two errors.

```
module.modulemap: Header '{My Framework Name}-Swift.h' not found.

Could not build Objective-C module '{My Framework Name}'.
```

### [image: Screenshot of archiving errors.]

I have three targets in my app, an app, widget, and framework.

### [image]

The framework has a collection of Swift files, as well as an Objective-C header with these contents:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double XScheduleKitVersionNumber;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char XScheduleKitVersionString[];
```

My Mac is running OS X 10.10.2.  Xcode is version 6.3.  My app is for iOS 8.0+.  The full content of the project I'm working on is open-source and available at https://github.com/Cin316/X-Schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into this frustrating problem before myself. It seems that with pure Swift framework targets the Objective-C header file causes intermittent or strange build errors (Xcode bug?). It seems counter-intuitive but part of the solution at least is to either change the header file from public to project or simply remove it from the build target. I wish I had a better explanation as to why this works!

I have forked your project and created a build (that works on my machine at least) here: https://github.com/acwright/X-Schedule

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help!  However, I'm still having trouble archiving my project, with the same error as I had before.  I can compile it, just like I could before.  How are you archiving/compiling it?  I am just selecting Product->Archive through the Xcode menu.  Does your pull request archive for you?  What version of Xcode are you running?

Comment: Yes. I am able to archive (after changing code signing) but... I just realized that I can ONLY after also linking the framework target to the widget target under General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries. I will update by pull request so you can try it.

Comment: Update: I was just able to get it to work by adding my framework as a member of the widget target.  I can archive this successfully now.  You did the same thing I did just through a slightly different method.  Thank you!  Do you mind if I list your name in the credits of the app?

Comment: Thats great! I would have no problem with that!